# jms/serializer unable to install

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using symfony 2.8, when I try to install jms/serializer bundle using composer it shows this error,

```
composer require jms/serializer-bundle

Problem 1
- jms/serializer-bundle 1.0.0 requires jms/serializer ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by jms/serializer[1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0].
- jms/serializer-bundle 1.5.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- jms/serializer-bundle 1.4.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- jms/serializer-bundle 1.3.1 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- jms/serializer-bundle 1.3.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- jms/serializer-bundle 1.2.1 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- jms/serializer-bundle 1.2.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- jms/serializer-bundle 1.1.0 requires php >=5.4.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- jms/serializer 1.9.0 requires php >=5.5.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- jms/serializer 1.8.1 requires php >=5.5.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (5.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

How can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

In my composer.json, remove the following lines :

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.3.9"
    }
},
```

And Now its working.